# Rails: Can I use the ruby gem better_errors with any frontend framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js, better-errors-gem

I have a backboneJS app working with the `gem rabl` on `Ruby on Rails`

Comment: just to make sure, is ur app entirely ajax based ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady no actually I have some static pages that work with the `*html.erb` and the rest on `rabl>backboneJS`

Comment: well what i mean is, as long as that your pages load from the server ( not ajax ) you can easily use `better_errors` because when an error happens `better_errors` intercepts that errors and renders a better page, when you are using ajax, the page will still render, but it will returned in the ajax response, not the browser.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady that's a good point, any suggestion for my to test that? Sorry I just havened worked with backboneJS on rails before, the backboneJS app lives in my assets directory, so I use `ejs` views. That's why I think it might not be able to intercept it.

Comment: better error only shows ruby errors (or rather server side errors), if it's a javascript error it will occur on the browser not the server, if the assets has errors it should appear in the precompilation, so you probably are covered too, anyways, using better errors has no downsides, cause the cases that won't work with better errors won't work with the basic error pages without better errors.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks a bunch for the explanation :)! take all my upvotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better error only shows ruby errors (or rather server side errors), if it's a javascript error it will occur on the browser not the server, if the assets have errors it should appear in the precompilation, so you probably are covered too.

Anyways, using better errors has no downsides, cause the cases that won't work with better errors won't work with the basic error pages without better errors.

PS: If you want to debug an ajax request you can try opening the browser console and click the request that has an error and choose something that means close to '*open this request in a new tab*'